# Localization in button MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, localization

I am trying to create an mvc2 application

i need to apply localization

localization applied to labels works fine.

but i don't know how apply localization in button value.

my code is:

```
<input type="submit" value="<%: MVC.App_GlobalResources.Button.LogOn_Submit %>" class="login_button_75" />
```

please help me

thanks

suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it correct by the following code
It works cool...

```
 <input type="submit" value="<%: GetGlobalResourceObject("Button","LogOn_Submit") %>" class="login_button_75" />
```

suraj

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a great post](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) on how to implement localization in asp.net mvc 2. What you need to write in order to access the string inside your resource is the following:

Given that the Resource Namespace is `MyResourceNamespace` and the Resource name is `MyPageResource` and the Name of the resource object you want to use is `Login_Submit` you can write:

<% MyREsourceNamespace.MyPageResource.Login_Submit %>

And to apply this to your value you can write:

`<input type="submit" value="<%: MyREsourceNamespace.MyPageResource.Login_Submit %>" class="login_button_75" />`